# Since when did inertial mass and gravitional mass became equal?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, mass, equivalence-principle

If we think about inertial mass and gravitational mass as independent concepts and develop physics then we would know after a while they are only propotional (by precision we have by now). but it seem physicist say they are equal. when in history they became equal? two guesses:

1. Newton himself says gravitional force is propotional to product of inertial masses and doesn't bring to play another thing such as gravitational mass. then this gravitional force itself acts on inertial masses and produces acceleration.
2. this two masses were propotional and somewhere in history physicist changed units to coefficient of proportionality became one.

Comment: It’s a convention. You could double every gravitational mass by reducing the gravitational constant by a factor of 4.

Comment: We don't know if they are equal. We are making a very strong experimental effort to reduce the uncertainty in the hypotheses that they are not. So far we haven't been able to detect any deviation from the equivalence principle.

Comment: [Eötvös experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_experiment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They became *the same thing* when Einstein advanced his general theory of relativity. That would put it at sometime after 1915.

Comment: I would point out that perhaps GR simply traded one mass concept for another.  In GR, the mass-energy that causes spacetime curvature, and the mass-energy that causes inertia, are conceptually different (or could be) no?

Comment: No, they are identical- and indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

Once you know that the gravitational mass and the inertial mass are proportional, then it is just a choice of units to make them equal. Suppose that we have units of inertial mass, $m$, such that $$\vec F_{net}=m \ \vec a$$ Suppose further that we have units of gravitational mass, $m_g$, that are proportional to inertial mass such that $m_g=k \ m$. Now, in these units the magnitude of the gravitational force is $$F_g=G_g \ \frac{m_{g1} \ m_{g2}}{r^2}$$ but we can express this in terms of inertial mass as $$F_g=G_g \ \frac{m_{g1} \ m_{g2}}{r^2}=G_g \ \frac{k \ m_{1} \ k \ m_{2}}{r^2} = G_i \ \frac{m_{1} \ m_{2}}{r^2}$$ where $G_i=k^2 G_g$ is the gravitational constant in the units where we have simply dropped the gravitational mass and we only use inertial mass. So in those units the gravitational law is written in terms of $G_i$ and the inertial mass and gravitational mass are the same.

Comment: Many thanks. but my question is rather historical. sometimes history helps to understand. Does Newton thought about them separetaly? may be not. and may be we think about them separately after comparing Newton's gravitational force by Coulomb formula. and other posibilities some of them I said in question and may be answer is another thing.

Comment: Then the question doesn't belong here. Historical questions should go to the History of Science and Math stack exchange.